# Reentrant Locks with overriden method?

Tags: java, locking, java-threads

```
public class A
{
   public synchronized void doSomething()
   {
       System.out.println("Class A");
   }
}

public class B extends A
{
    public synchronized void doSomething()
    {
        System.out.println("Class B");
        super.doSomething();
    }
}
```

I am new to threads and need to understand the below property of locking.
I am unable to understand the significance of reentrancy in above code. it is said if reentrency were not implemented, the above code will deadlock.

Answer (score 2):

When a thread `T` calls `B.doSomething()` it will obtain a lock on the instance `i` of type `B`. Then it calls `super.doSomething()` which requires to obtain a lock on `i` before permitting entrance. Because `T` already obtained a lock for `i` it may pass without obtainingit once again (which would not be possible until it releases its lock obtained before).

This behavior, free passage if a thread `T` already owns a lock he must obtain, is called a reentrant lock.

Maybe you want to read the javadoc for [ReentrantLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) which explains the concept as well.